# The same in one, distinct in two

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> I'm three in some senses,
>   I'm known to tempest,
>   I'm prime observation,
>   and concur in translation.

What am I?

> "concur in translation" is not technically precisely accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you

> Sea, see, sì?

"I'm three in some senses"

> The answer is a triple homophone

"I'm known to tempest"

> A tempest is a violent storm, typically used to describe storms that happen at **sea**

"I'm prime observation"

> The prime mode of observation is seeing, thus "see"

"and concur in translation"

> In Spanish: "yes" is "sì"